# Sync AWS S3 bucket/folder locally

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a system with user accounts distributed between projects. The projects have each a folder structure with uploaded files. The documents are stored on AWS S3. Through the portal the users are able to manage (CRUD) the folders and documents.

But I also want to implement a client application that syncs a local folder with the different projects folders. Does AWS have such an API? I know about the cli tool [S3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd-sync), is that the way to go?

Or does AWS have an API (preferably for NodeJS) that works with this kind of functionality, syncing a local folder with an S3 folder?

What would be the 'correct way' (if any) to go?

Comment: AWS Stogare Gateway maybe what you are looking for
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/latest/userguide/WhatIsStorageGateway.html

Comment: Also, S3 to NFS with Storage Gateway in action
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tP5edaxBEEI

Comment: If you're looking for a command-line tool, these days it is recommended to use the official [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) rather than s3cmd.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3-sync) npm module for sync s3 folder

Install npm module

```
npm install s3-sync
```

Use module in your code segment

```
var stream = s3sync({
    key: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY
  , secret: process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY
  , bucket: 'sync-testing'
})

stream.write({
    src: __filename
  , dest: '/uploader.js'
})

stream.end({
    src: __dirname + '/README.md'
  , dest: '/README.md'
})
```

More details refer [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3-sync)

Comment: how to download? Is there any solution that provides both upload/download capability ?